# How to sum two numbers and print them in field

Tags: javafx

I create fields, and button, my problem is how to make button works on click to sum entered numbers and print sum in new already created field.

My code is:

```
    GridPane gp = new GridPane();

    Text txt1 = new Text("Number 1: ");
    Text txt2 = new Text("Number 2: ");
    Text txt3 = new Text("Result: ");
    TextField number1 = new TextField();
    TextField number2 = new TextField();
    TextField result = new TextField();
    Button btn1 = new Button("Sum");

    gp.add(txt1, 0, 0);
    gp.add(txt2, 0, 1);
    gp.add(txt3, 0, 3);
    gp.add(number1, 1, 0);
    gp.add(number2, 1, 1);
    gp.add(result, 1, 3);
    gp.add(btn1, 1, 2);

    gp.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    btn1.setOnAction(e -> {

    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(gp, 600, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to parse the values in the text field to integers so that you can add them

```
Integer.parseInt(number1.getText())
```

Then you just add the integers

```
int sum = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText())+Integer.parseInt(number2.getText());
```

Then you need to get the string value of the int so you can set it in the text field

```
String.valueOf(sum)
```

The final result looks like this

```
btn1.setOnAction(e -> {
    int sum = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText())+Integer.parseInt(number2.getText());
    result.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
});
```

Comment: If this answer satisfies your question please upvote and accept the answer(clicking the grey check next to the question) so that others do not think this question is still open.